# Navigation Controller with static table cells?

Tags: iphone, ios5

I'm trying to add a view that is a form that has 3 elements. These elements will be inside of a static grouped table.  I need a navigation bar at the top with a "Save" and "Cancel" button.  Both buttons should send the user back to their previous screen when tapped.

Within the storyboard, I have tried creating a Navigation Controller and then adding a table to it, but I get the error of "Static table view are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController".

So, I tried creating a Table View Controller, but the storyboard won't let me put a navigation bar into one of those for some reason...

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add UITableViewController to your storyboard and then choose Editor > Embed in > Navigation Bar Controller from the menu. This will wrap your table view controller in a nav bar controller and you can then add your Save and Cancel buttons to the navigation bar.

It might seem a bit wasteful to create a navigation controller with only a single sub-controller just to get a navigation bar but it's the accepted way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Oh... this iOS stuff is hurting my head.

I wanted to do the same thing, have a TableView, with a Navigation Bar at the top, but there was no "Embed in.. Navigation Bar" menu item, just "Embed in..  Navigation Controller".

Eventually, solving this was easier than I thought.

I just needed to add a *Table View Controller* to my storyboard, then CTRL+drag a Segue from the "calling" view controller to my new Table View Controller, and, voila, it gives me the Navigation Bar straightaway.